# Brush Function in Parallel Coordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

In the parallel coordinate code in [this link](http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281), I can't understand the "brush" function, properly.

```
function brush() {
     var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) { return !y[p].brush.empty(); }),
         extents = actives.map(function(p) { return y[p].brush.extent(); });
     foreground.style("display", function(d) {
         return actives.every(function(p, i) {
                          return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
        }) ? null : "none";
     });
}
```

What is p in this code? what is i?

In this part of code `return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];`, we are looking for the data that we are interested in (data which is inside the rectangle we drew), right? How can I get the row index of this data for future processing?

Comment: `p` is one of the things being operated on, i.e. a dimension or an active. `i` is the index of the respective element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I modify the code to get the index of the data which is between `extents[i][0]` and `extents[i][1]`?

Comment: That would be just `i`, no?